# Appending new objects to a list in a separate variable

Tags: python, object, variables, input, append

I'm a little confused on how to append a new object to a list. I feel like I'm overthinking it, but let me know if I'm on the right track here.

**EDIT:** Removed old code

To be clear, I don't want to edit the text file referenced in display() directly (and then read off that), I want to use the append method to add a new book to the end of the list. I get the objects through a split using a semicolon, so when I'm adding new books, should they also have the semicolon present to match the rest of the list?

**EDIT:** Here is what I have now.

```
class Book: 

    def __init__(self, title, author, isbn, callnumber, stock, loaned):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.isbn = isbn
        self.callnumber = callnumber
        self.stock = stock
        self.loaned = loaned
        self.available = int(self.stock)-int(self.loaned)

    def getTitle(self):
        return self.title

    def getAuthor(self):
        return self.author

    def getISBN(self):
        return self.isbn

    def getCallNumber(self):
        return self.callnumber

    def getStock(self):
        return self.stock

    def getLoaned(self):
        return self.loaned

    def getAvailable(self):
        return self.available

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.title + '\t' + self.author + '\t' + self.isbn + '\t' + self.callnumber + '\t' + self.stock + '\t' + self.loaned + '\n'

    def inventory():
        fmtstring = '''{:<50}\t{:<20}\t{:<13}\t{:<13}\t{:<10}\t{:<10}\t{:<10}'''
        print(fmtstring.format("Name","Author","ISBN","Call Number","Stock","Loaned","Available"))
        books = []
        with open("books.txt", "r") as inventoryfile:
            for line in inventoryfile:
                strip_lines=line.strip()
                inventory = strip_lines.split(";")
                book = (Book(inventory[0],inventory[1],inventory[2],inventory[3],inventory[4],inventory[5]))
                books.append(book)
                print(fmtstring.format(*fields(book)))

    @staticmethod
    def input_book():
        title = input("Provide the title of the book> ")
        author = input("Provide the author of the book> ")
        isbn = input("Provide the ISBN of the book> ")
        callnumber = input("Provide the call number of the book> ")
        stock = input("Provide the stock of the book> ")
        return Book(title, author, isbn, callnumber, stock, 0)


And these are called on with menu options.

    while True:
        print()
        print("Westlands Book Inventory Management Subsystem")
        print("1. Display Inventory")
        print("2. Add a Book")
        print("3. Remove a Book")
        print("4. Export Inventory")
        print("5. Quit IMS")
        choice=eval(input("Select an option from the menu> "))
        if(choice==1):
            print()
            print("Displaying Westlands Books Inventory")
            print()
            Book.inventory()
        
        elif(choice==2):
            print()
            print("Adding a Book")
            print()
            Book.input_book()
            print()
            print('Book added successfully.')
```

This is the "safe" version of my code that doesn't break anything. I've tried the append command in various places but doesn't seem to be  working. I can't seem to return what was input into input_books at all. Thanks

Comment: You need to indent the method definitions to make them part of the `Book` class.

Comment: Yeah that was already done, it just didn't display correctly when I pasted it over for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function that creates a `Book` from user input should just `return` that `Book` rather than trying to add it to a list (primarily because: what list?).  If it's a method on `Book`, it should be a static method (or a class method), not an instance method, since the point of it is to *create* an instance.  For example:

```
@staticmethod
def input_book():
    title = input("Provide the title of the book> ")
    author = input("Provide the author of the book> ")
    isbn = input("Provide the ISBN of the book> ")
    callnumber = input("Provide the call number of the book> ")
    stock = input("Provide the stock of the book> ")
    return Book(title, author, isbn, callnumber, stock, 0)
```

Now *outside* your `Book` class, you can do:

```
books = []
while True:
    print()
    print("Westlands Book Inventory Management Subsystem")
    print("1. Display Inventory")
    print("2. Add a Book")
    choice = input("Select an option from the menu> ")
    if choice == "1":
        print(books)
    if choice == "2":
        print()
        print("Adding a Book")
        print()
        books.append(Book.input_book())
        print()
        print('Book added successfully.')
```

Note that `books` isn't a `Book`, it's a *`list` of `Book`s*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've implemented your code but I seem to be misunderstanding something because regardless of where I put the append command you provided, it doesn't seem to be working. I can't even get what put into input_book to return properly.

I've edited my original post to give an updated version of what I'm working with currently.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't run because the indentation is wrong.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make sense for `inventory` to be part of the `Book` class -- and it shouldn't create its own list, it should operate on a list that you pass it.

Comment: So it sounds like I need to turn the inventory function into a display function (just displaying the current list) that reads off a different list, the same one that input_book adds to. This seems to be at the root of the confusion, as no wonder I'm having issues adding to this list, as it's created by the inventory function rather than being referenced. How should I do this based on what I have right now?

Comment: Additionally, when simply choosing to test the input_book function by printing the contents of books, I get an error that says "can only concatenate str (not "int") to str". I think this has something to do with the Available figure in the book object that runs some calculations, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: All fixed, don't worry mate!